# Should I monitor the SQL Server tempdb for user activity?

Tags: sql-server, auditing, tempdb

I am currently auditing all databases on `SQL Server 2008 R2` for specific events. I get alot of events generated for **tempdb.**

Do I need to monitor **tempdb** or is it alright to exclude the **tempdb**?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The question is : what kind of events do you want to track ?

Comment: @Richard Events 47, 102, 103, 104, 105, 108, 109, 110, 111, 113, 117, 130, 170, 171, 173, 176 is what I am monitoring. Basically monitoring database account activity.